# Concatenating CSS files in a specific order

Tags: css, ant, concatenation, minify

I have a series of CSS files that I am concatenating and minfying (using the YUI Compressor) with an Ant build script.  The CSS files are:

- Reset.css
- Formalize.css
- Typography.css
- Site.css

There are other CSS files like ie.css and editor.css that I don't want to include in the minification.  I have my build script working with the following code, but the problem now is that the files need to be concatenated in the order posted above.

```
<target name="minifycss">
    <!-- Combine all CSS files except for ones specified for IE or the content editor -->
    <concat destfile="css/e123-1.css">
        <fileset dir="css" includes="*.css" excludes="ie.css editor.css print.css" />
    </concat>

    <!-- Minify the css -->
    <java fork="true" jar="${yuicompressor.lib}" dir="css" output="css/e123-1.min.css">
        <arg value="e123-1.css" />
    </java>
</target>
```

I assume that the files are added alphabetically, but I was wondering if there was a way to tell Ant what order to concatenate the files without renaming them to 1reset.css, 2formalize.css, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a filelist, as shown in the [ant concat documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html).

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet.  I actually did end up appending numbers to my file names, so that way I can add CSS files without editing the Ant build, but your answer was correct for the question I asked so I awarded you the answer... that and no one else posted.

Answer (score 1):

If using [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j), you can control the order of the resources to concatenate like this:

```
      <groups>
         <group name="all">
           <css>/static/reset.css</css>
           <css>/static/fonts.css</css>
           <css>/wildcard/*.css</css>
           <js>/static/js/lib/core.js</js>
         </group>
      </groups>
```

It allows you to use wildcards and also can be used for javascript resources (not only css)

This is a biased answer, because i'm working on wro4j project.